# Is there a technique for glacé (glazing) that could speed up the process?

Tags: fruit, shortcuts

I saw a recipe for glacéing (is that a word?) cherries, and at one stage they required anywhere from 10 days to 3 weeks soaking time.  Are there any techniques that could speed this up, or am I just being a nervous New Yorker?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you have a link to the recipe? Are you referring to maraschino cherries?

Comment: This recipe is about a week, I've seen others that call for 3 weeks: http://recipeland.com/recipe/v/Glace-Fruit--and-Fruit-Syrup-47791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try forcing whatever it is into the cherries.  This can be done under pressure, which you might be [able to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMQRSJUFuwM) using a [fizzgizz?](http://www.fizzgiz.com/) or maybe [with a creamer](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/08/11/infusion-profusion-game-changing-fast-%E2%80%98n-cheap-technique/), or simply by vacuum packing the cherries with the soaking liquid.  once vacuum packed you might be able to put in a pressure cooker to increase the pressure, but I'm not sure what the heat would do to the cherries.

EDIT:  having read the recipe, I'm not sure any of this would work.